# Execute SQL from file in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, database, sqlalchemy

How can I execute whole sql file into database using SQLAlchemy? There can be many different sql queries in the file including begin and commit/rollback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not aware of a good general answer for this. Some dbapi's (psycopg2 for instance) support executing many statements at a time. If the files aren't huge you can just load them into a string and execute them on a connection. For others, I would try to use a command-line client for that db and pipe the data into that using the subprocess module.

If those approaches aren't acceptable, then you'll have to go ahead and implement a small SQL parser that can split the file apart into separate statements. This is really tricky to get 100% correct, as you'll have to factor in database dialect specific literal escaping rules, the charset used, any database configuration options that affect literal parsing (e.g. PostgreSQL standard_conforming_strings).

If you only need to get this 99.9% correct, then some regexp magic should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 25):

#### `sqlalchemy.text` or `sqlalchemy.sql.text`

- The `text` construct provides a straightforward method to directly execute `.sql` files.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text
# or from sqlalchemy.sql import text

engine = create_engine('mysql://{USR}:{PWD}@localhost:3306/db', echo=True)

with engine.connect() as con:
    with open("src/models/query.sql") as file:
        query = text(file.read())
        con.execute(query)
```

- [SQLAlchemy: Using Textual SQL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql)

  - [`text()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text)

Comment: is it a good idea to open the file using the `with` too?

Comment: Sure, that would be cleaner.

Comment: Does this support creating #temp tables which are used in subsequent queries of the same file? Also what making a about global ##temp table in that is referenced in a second file that is executed in the same way (query by query)?

Answer (score 15):

I was able to run .sql schema files using pure SQLAlchemy and some string manipulations. It surely isn't an elegant approach, but it works.

```py
# Open the .sql file
sql_file = open('file.sql','r')

# Create an empty command string
sql_command = ''

# Iterate over all lines in the sql file
for line in sql_file:
    # Ignore commented lines
    if not line.startswith('--') and line.strip('\n'):
        # Append line to the command string
        sql_command += line.strip('\n')

        # If the command string ends with ';', it is a full statement
        if sql_command.endswith(';'):
            # Try to execute statement and commit it
            try:
                session.execute(text(sql_command))
                session.commit()

            # Assert in case of error
            except:
                print('Ops')

            # Finally, clear command string
            finally:
                sql_command = ''
```

It iterates over all lines in a .sql file ignoring commented lines.
Then it concatenates lines that form a full statement and tries to execute the statement. You just need a file handler and a session object.

Comment: Nice and it would be nice to use `with open('','')` and use the `SQLAlchemy` class in the `session` area. This is how it worked for and the former help to clean up after file read access...

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work for all dialects. E.g. PostgreSQL requires multiple `;` in a single statement when creating functions.

Comment: This raises the question of why use sqlalchemy for this part, may be better just use the underlying DB driver for loading the file

Answer (score 11):

You can do it with SQLalchemy and psycopg2.

```
file = open(path)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_url)
escaped_sql = sqlalchemy.text(file.read())
engine.execute(escaped_sql)
```

Comment: This will not work with all dialects. SQLite e.g. explicitly disallows executing multiple queries in one "execute" command.

Comment: @ThePadawan pysqlite does provide executescript so a simple conditional check would allow it through a raw_connection

Comment: I believe this will have problems with DDL.  Alchemy detects DDL and creates an implicit transaction that is left open.  This is the problem I'm having, because all my scripts break via alchemy if DDL is present.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using sqlite3 it has a useful extension to dbapi called conn.executescript(str), I've hooked this up via something like this and it seemed to work: (Not all context is shown but it should be enough to get the drift)

```
def init_from_script(script):
    Base.metadata.drop_all(db_engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(db_engine)     

    # HACK ALERT: we can do this using sqlite3 low level api, then reopen session.
    f = open(script)
    script_str = f.read().strip()
    global db_session
    db_session.close()
    import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file_name)
    conn.executescript(script_str)
    conn.commit()

    db_session = Session()
```

Is this pure evil I wonder? I looked in vain for a 'pure' sqlalchemy equivalent, perhaps that could be added to the library, something like db_session.execute_script(file_name) ? I'm hoping that db_session will work just fine after all that (ie no need to restart engine) but not sure yet... further research needed (ie do we need to get a new engine or just a session after going behind sqlalchemy's back?)

FYI sqlite3 includes a related routine: sqlite3.complete_statement(sql) if you roll your own parser...

Answer (score 5):

You can access the raw DBAPI connection through this

```py
    raw_connection = mySqlAlchemyEngine.raw_connection()
    raw_cursor = raw_connection() #get a hold of the proxied DBAPI connection instance
```

but then it will depend on which dialect/driver you are using which can be referred to through this [list](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/index.html).

For pyscog2, you can just do

```py
    raw_cursor.execute(open("my_script.sql").read())
```

but pysqlite you would need to do

```py
    raw_cursor.executescript(open("my_script").read())
```

and in line with that you would need to check the documentation of whichever DBAPI driver you are using to see if multiple statements are allowed in one execute or if you would need to use a helper like `executescript` which is unique to pysqlite.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to run the script splitting the statements, and running each statement directly with a ["connectionless" execution](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#connectionless-execution-implicit-execution) with the SQLAlchemy Engine. This assumes that each statement ends with a `;` and that there's no more than one statement per line.

```
engine = create_engine(url)
with open('script.sql') as file:
    statements = re.split(r';\s*$', file.read(), flags=re.MULTILINE)
    for statement in statements:
        if statement:
            engine.execute(text(statement))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the current answers, I did not found a solution which works when a combination of these features in the .SQL file is present:

- Comments with "--"
- Multi-line statements with additional comments after "--"
- Function definitions which have multiple SQL-queries ending with ";" butmust be executed as a whole statement

A found a rather simple solution:

```
# check for /* */
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    assert '/*' not in f.read(), 'comments with /* */ not supported in SQL file python interface'

# we check out the SQL file line-by-line into a list of strings (without \n, ...)
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    queries = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

# from each line, remove all text which is behind a '--'
def cut_comment(query: str) -> str:
    idx = query.find('--')
    if idx >= 0:
        query = query[:idx]
    return query

# join all in a single line code with blank spaces
queries = [cut_comment(q) for q in queries]
sql_command = ' '.join(queries)

# execute in connection (e.g. sqlalchemy)
conn.execute(sql_command)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code bellow works for me in alembic migrations

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from ekrec.common import get_project_root


def upgrade():
    path = f'{get_project_root()}/migrations/versions/fdb8492f75b2_.sql'
    op.execute(open(path).read())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had success with David's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070610/13071019), with two slight modifications:

1. Use `get_bind()` as I was working with a Session rather than an Engine
2. Call `cursor()` on the raw connection

```
raw_connection = myDbSession.get_bind().raw_connection()
raw_cursor = raw_connection.cursor()
raw_cursor.execute(open("my_script.sql").read())
```