# SQLAlchemy execute script file with multiple SQL statements in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to a SQLite database. I would like to execute some file, `script.sql`, which contains **multiple** SQL statements.

Previously, I was using the `sqlite3` library and running

```
with sqlite3.connect('my_database.db') as conn:
  with open('script.sql') as s:
    conn.executescript(s.read())
```

Moving to `SQLAlchemy`, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268050/execute-sql-from-file-in-sqlalchemy), from which I wrote new code using a `session` instance:

```
session.execute(text(s.read())
```

However, this returns an error, because my script contains multiple statements.

```
sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time.
```

What is the best way to execute a large script file with multiple statements using `SQLAlchemy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy itself only calls the cursor's `execute` method, which does not support executing multiple statements.  However it's possible to access the DB API connection directly, and call its `executescript` method:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///so72341960.db')

# Create a table for our example.
tbl = sa.Table(
    'mytable',
    sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String),
)

# Ensure we start with a clean table.
tbl.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
tbl.create(engine)

SQL = """
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('Alice');
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('Bob');
"""

with engine.begin() as conn:
    dbapi_conn = conn.connection
    dbapi_conn.executescript(SQL)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because sqlite3 only supports executing one statement at a time. If you want to execute multiple statements, they need to be separate commands. For example,

```py
statements = [] // put your statements in this array
for statement in statements:
  session.execute(text(statement))
```

This will iterate over the array of statements and execute each one in turn.

Comment: `sqlite3` supports mutliple statements, as I showed in my first example. And I can't easily separate my statements into an array, because they're all in one file. Are you aware of any method for separating multiple SQL statements from one string into an array of strings?